# What does "cat -" mean? Linux operators

Tags: linux

I've created a file called fruits consisting of strawberry, kiwi, and banana. I wanted to find strawberry using the `|` pipe.

```
cat fruits | grep strawberry
```

While learning, I understand that not all commands support `|`, and we need to use `cat -`. How do we use this command?

I've tried `cat - | grep strawberry` or `cat - fruits | grep strawberry`. Both runs but never stop.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16357/273492

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify a file name of `-`, `cat` reads standard input (your terminal).  It's a common convention; many other commands use `-` to indicate 'read standard input'.  You have to tell `cat` that you've reached EOF by typing <kbd>Control-D</kbd> on Unix-like systems, or <kbd>Control-Z</kbd> on Windows systems.

You have:

- `cat - | grep strawberry` — this will run until you indicate EOF.
- `cat - fruits | grep strawberry` — this too runs until you indicate EOF, but then processes the file `fruits` too.

You say "not all commands support `|`".  That is barely true.  The shell implements the `|` operator.  If a program is a pure generator (for example, `ls` or `ps`), then it will ignore standard input, so piping data to `ls` or `ps` is pointless.  But piping the output of the commands makes sense.

You also mention using:

```
cat fruits | grep strawberry
```

That certainly works, but it is unnecessary — you could use

```
grep strawberry fruits
```

to avoid the overhead of the extra process and the pipe.  This is an example of [UUoC — Useless Use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11710552/15168).

Answer (score 1):

If `cat -` doesn't stop it's because the symbol "-" is for parameter. And you run `cat` with no parameter. Actually, it didn't run indefinitely; the shell waits for you to enter the end of the command.

`cat` is a command that simply reads files.

In your example, it will read your file `fruits`. And the pipe `|` means the output of `cat` will be the input of your `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to use some options after `cat -`

Suppose if you use `cat -n file_name` it will show you the content of the file by giving it the line number

Comment: The dash on its own has a specific meaning, unrelated to options like `-n`.  You can even repeat it: `cat - -` is legitimate if unorthodox (and decidedly different from `cat --`).